# On click if value inside of input type text is more than 10 then do this

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display a message to the user if they enter a value more than 10 inside of this input.

This is the input field with a "calculate" button:

```
<div class="form__field">
    <label for="sd-property-value" class="form__label">Property Value: </label>
    <input type="text" id="sd-property-value" class="sd-property-value currency input-text" name="sd-calc" />
</div>

<div class="calculator-controls">
    <p><button id="sd-Calculate" class="button">Calculate</button></p>
</div>
```

This is the jquery:

```
$('#sd-Calculate').on('click', function () {

    var checkInput = parseInt($('#sd-property-value').val());

        console.log('new clicker');
        console.log(checkInput);

    if (checkInput > 50) {
        console.log('more than');
        } else {
            console.log("less than");
        }
    });
```

Console log keeps returning NaN.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `parseInt($('#sd-property-value').val().trim() || 0, 10);`

Comment: Would you mind accepting my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) below - if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

I have added `div` which will show the message to the user if the value is more then `10` or if there a value less then 10 a message will be shown as well.

Run snippet below.

```js
$('#sd-Calculate').on('click', function() {
  var checkInput = parseInt($('#sd-property-value').val());
  if (checkInput <= 10) {
$('#message').text('You must enter more then 10')
  } else if (checkInput > 10) {
$('#message').text('You value is more then 10')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form__field">
  <label for="sd-property-value" class="form__label">Property Value: </label>
  <input type="text" id="sd-property-value" class="sd-property-value currency input-text" name="sd-calc" />
</div>

<div class="calculator-controls">
  <p><button id="sd-Calculate" class="button">Calculate</button></p>
</div>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of parseInt, could you please try below

```
var checkInput = +($('#sd-property-value').val());
```

This will return zero if the value is empty. But it will be NaN if user type string in input field. So add NaN checking like below

```
$('#sd-Calculate').on('click', function () {

        var checkInput = +($('#sd-property-value').val());

            console.log('new clicker');
            console.log(checkInput);

        if (!Number.isNaN(checkInput) && checkInput > 50) {
            console.log('more than');
            } else {
                console.log("less than");
            }
        });
```

If you want to prevent typing string in text box, change the type as 'number'

```
<input type="number" id="sd-property-value" class="sd-property-value currency input-text" name="sd-calc" />
```

Comment: still returns NaN

Comment: @Danny91 the question asked for *"More than 10"*

Comment: @Danny91 I corrected the if condition, please check